# Error in publishing Jupyter notebook to medium

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science, medium.com-publishing-api

I am trying to publish a jupyter notebook as a medium blog , I installed all the necessary libraries, then I put in my integration token too and every other details but I am getting this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPSX0.png)

Failed to post to Medium

Returned error message below

"ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_bundler.py", line 71, in upload
data = publish(**kwargs)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py", line 449, in publish
p.main()
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py", line 309, in main
self.md, self.image_data_dict = self.create_markdown()
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_publish_to_medium.py", line 165, in create_markdown
no_ex_pp.preprocess(self.nb, self.resources)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nbconvert/preprocessors/base.py", line 70, in preprocess
nb.cells[index], resources = self.preprocess_cell(cell, resources, index)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_preprocesors.py", line 204, in preprocess_cell
output["data"] = {"image/png": converter(html)}
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_screenshot.py", line 183, in run
img_str = self.finalize_image(img)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jupyter_to_medium/_screenshot.py", line 174, in finalize_image
mimage.imsave(buffer, img)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 1652, in imsave
rgba = sm.to_rgba(arr, bytes=True)
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/matplotlib/cm.py", line 474, in to_rgba
if norm and (xx.max() > 1 or xx.min() < 0):
File "/home/binit/anaconda3/envs/statistics/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 41, in _amax
return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
"

I am trying to publish a jupyter notebook as a medium blog , I installed all the necessary libraries, then I put in my integration token too and every other details but I get this error.